# Compile error caused by vba 'Left' trim function in string parser

Tags: vba, excel

Im attempting to create a vba function to parse strings of text line by line into an excel table. I'd like the function to only print sub-strings that are between two characters in each line. For example, html tags. While debugging, the `Right()` function does what I'd like. But the `Left()` function will not even compile. The error message is very little help, "Invalid procedure call or argument". What is going on? I didn't change that line of code at all and it was just working.

to explain what im trying to accomplish, lets say i'm parsing html text. Id like to only view text inside the "<" and ">" tags. but I'm also trying to code it so I could use this to parse substrings between any two desired characters.

so text like this:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

will print:

```
html
head
/head
body
/body
/html
```

It was just working. Not sure why I'm getting this error. Only for the `Left()` trim.

```
Sub ParseTextFromFile()
Dim myFileName As String
Dim myLine As String
Dim FileNum As Long
Dim n As Integer
n = 1

myFileName = "C:\Users\user\Desktop\myfile.TXT"
FileNum = FreeFile
Close FileNum
Open myFileName For Input As FileNum
Do While Not EOF(FileNum)
    Line Input #FileNum, myLine
    'Debug.Print TrimString(CStr(myLine))
    Cells(n, 1).Value = TrimString(CStr(myLine))
    n = n + 1
Loop

MsgBox "" & n - 1 & " items added."
End Sub

'parses a string between two chars/string key values
Function TrimString(s As String) As String
    Dim indexOfKey As Integer
    Dim firstTrim As String
    Dim secondTrim As String
    Dim textLength As Integer
    Dim key1 As String
    Dim key2 As String
    firstTrim = ""
    secondTrim = ""

    key1 = CStr(Cells(5, 8)) 'H5 = "<"
    key2 = CStr(Cells(6, 8)) 'H6 = ">"

    'remove everything to the left of the first appearance of the key char/string
    indexOfKey = InStr(1, s, key1)
    firstTrim = Right(s, Len(s) - indexOfKey)

    'remove everything to the right of the second appearance of the key char/string
    indexOfKey = InStr(1, firstTrim, key2)
    secondTrim = Left(firstTrim, indexOfKey - 1) 'this line is throwing the error

    TrimString = secondTrim
End Function
```

Comment: have you debugged it? Could be a negative index

Comment: Just tested this (hardcoding in the keys) and received no errors.  As @EngJon suggested, I'd step through this line by line and ensure you're seeing what you'd expect.

Comment: This error is only thrown if the second parameter of Left is negative. Although, when trying it by myself, I couldn't bring the function to produce that error...

Comment: If key is not found `InStr` will return 0. If every words in your text file is bounded left and right by only one character, you could use `TrimString = Mid(s, 2, Len(s) - 2)`. This will work independantly of the bounding characters.